# modify precision of a decision tree in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, class, tree, decision-tree

I created a regression tree using fitrtree
I want to take parameters such as CutPoint and reduce the precision, something like this:

```
tree.CutPoint=round(tree.CutPoint,5);
```

but I cannot do this because CutPoint is set as read only, I want to either modify it or create a tree that is essentially the same as this one but with those modifications. Unfortunately, documentation only show constructors trough the fitrtree function. Is it possible to do this? and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partly suggestive solution. I hope someone else will come up with a better solution.

**Non-functioning solutions:**

Typically, whenever such a problem occur, the (tedious) solution is to find the constructor of the class and then give the constructor all the fields including your `round(tree.CutPoint,5)` as `CutPoint`, i.e. something like this

```
NewTree = RegressionTree('X',tree.X,'Y',tree.Y,...,'CutPoint',round(tree.CutPoint,5),...)
```

which in theory should create a new tree, `NewTree` which is identical to `tree`, except for the `CutPoint` which have been rounded.

However, looking in the documentation (or help center) of the constructor it says

> An object of this class cannot be created by calling the constructor. Use FITRTREE to create a RegressionTree object by fitting the tree to training data.

So this approach will not work either. I then tried to go further up in the hierarchy of classes to see if one could do it with those methods and then evolve it downward, this was not (of what I could find) possible either.

**My suggestions:**

It seems like Mathworks have gone to a great length in ensuring that we do not tamper with the resulting tree. Thus my basic suggestion is to not use this method. This can however be done in several ways:

- It seems like all code for constructing the trees is available if you type e.g. `edit RegressionTree` thus you should be able to find the point where the resulting tree is set to `private`, which can then be changed to `public`.
- If you are not into changing existing Matlab code, then Kota Hara have made his own implementation of [binary regression trees](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42130-boosted-binary-regression-trees), which you could try out.
- The last suggestion is to implement it yourself, noting that you do not need to program a very general method only one which solves your problem. This can then be in any language.

As said in the beginning, I hope someone has more luck than me, though I highly doubt it as it seems Mathworks have done quite some work in keeping you from it - maybe there is an exploit, but I do not know it.